# Separate Java and HTML in jsp?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, servlet-3.0

I want to separate the java code (in a servlet) from the html code.
This code show the data of the mySql table in jsp.

What is the best practice without using scriptlet?

Thanks for your help.

```
<%
   String id = request.getParameter("userId");
   String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
   String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/";
   String dbName = "db";
   String userId = "root";
   String password = "root";

   try {
   Class.forName(driverName);
   } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   }

   Connection connection = null;
   Statement statement = null;
   ResultSet resultSet = null;
%>
<table>
   <td style="border:none"><a href="index.jsp" class="LinkButton">home</a> <br></td>
   <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>Data</th>
      .....
   </tr>
   <%
      try{ 
      connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl+dbName, userId, password);
      statement=connection.createStatement();
      String sql ="SELECT * FROM table";

      resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
      while(resultSet.next()){
   %>
   <tr>
      <td><%=resultSet.getString("id") %></td>
      <td><%=resultSet.getString("Data") %></td>
      ...
   </tr>
   <% 
      }

      } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      }
   %>
</table>
```

Comment: read about [JSTL](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnake.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Get method and servlets.
You can write all java codes in servlet which looks like :

```
public void doGet (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
  throws IOException, ServletException {
    String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/";
    String dbName = "db";
    String userId = "root";
    String password = "root";

    try {
       Class.forName(driverName);
     } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null; 
    try{ 
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl+dbName, userId, password);
    statement=connection.createStatement();
    String sql ="SELECT * FROM table";
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
    // Now convert this result set into a class having field id and data..
    // like MyClass{ String id; String data;}
    // make a list of List<MyClass>list = new ArrayList<>();
    request.setAttribute("list",list); 
    this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/yourPageName.jsp").
   include(request, response);
 }
```

Now get this attribute named "list" in your jsp file using `request.getAttribute("list");`. Typecast it into List.
And iterate it and print accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to separate the java codes then you might use JSTL

```
<jsp:include page="somecode.jsp" />
```

you can find more about it here

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_import_tag.htm

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/head-first-servlets/9780596516680/ch09s18.html

I think it will be best if you separate your logic from the view altogether, there are many frameworks which might help you to achieve this such as Spring MVC. If you want to implement without using any framework, you can follow the link below.

https://www.javatpoint.com/MVC-in-jsp

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to loop the While without scriptlet or JSTL, even if you can put database fetch job within servlet.

If you want to remove any server side script, need to divide the architecture with two tiers.

1. server side : servlet or JSP fetching database and generating JSON or CSV
2. client side : html calling the server side with AJAX to get pure data on load and then loop with javascript

and you don't use database connection pool but directly make database connection. It's quite expensive. and if you forget to close connection, you might run out of resources. very dangerous.